# What are the information sent to the server in the http request

Tags: browser, httprequest

When a request is sent to the server from the browser for a web page what are the information sent to the server in the `http` request? Can we check those information?If yes how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and you can inspect the HTTP headers of both the request and response.  That will work for either GET or POST requests.  You can do the same with Fiddler for IE.

Comment: I already have firebug. But can you tell me under which tab I will get this? Sorry to disturb you but seriously I have not got that.

Comment: Go to the Net tab and then find the GET `yourfilenamehere.html` entry, click the `+` to expand and then look at the Headers.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is the best for this (IMO)

You can save all requests in a particular session. Have it running in the background while you click away, then see what got sent over the wire. Replay requests, etc. The features go on and on.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that with Chrome using a right-click > inspect > ressources or under Firefox using Firebug.